# Displaying null pointer excepetion on second iteration at the time of writing in excel using JXL?

Tags: excel, selenium, frameworks, jxl

I am trying to set or write the result of execute test cases using JXL in key driven framework. Also, I am able to write or set the result but only in first iteration. At the time of second iteration it shows null pointer exception. I tried but don't understand what the exact problem is?

**Main Method:**

```
public class MainClass {
    private static final String BROWSER_PATH = "D:\\FF18\\firefox.exe";
    private static final String TEST_SUITE_PATH = "D:\\configuration\\GmailTestSuite.xls";
    private static final String OBJECT_REPOSITORY_PATH = "D:\\configuration\\objectrepository.xls";
    private static final String ADDRESS_TO_TEST = "https://www.gmail.com";

    // other constants

    private WebDriver driver;
    private Properties properties;

    /* private WebElement we; */

    public MainClass() {
        File file = new File(BROWSER_PATH);
        FirefoxBinary fb = new FirefoxBinary(file);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(fb, new FirefoxProfile());
        driver.get(ADDRESS_TO_TEST);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MainClass main = new MainClass();

        main.handleTestSuite();
    }

    private void handleTestSuite() throws Exception {
        ReadPropertyFile readConfigFile = new ReadPropertyFile();
        properties = readConfigFile.loadPropertiess();

        ExcelHandler testSuite = new ExcelHandler(TEST_SUITE_PATH, "Suite");
        testSuite.columnData();

        int rowCount = testSuite.rowCount();
        System.out.println("Total Rows=" + rowCount);

        for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
            String executable = testSuite.readCell(
                    testSuite.getCell("Executable"), i);
            System.out.println("Executable=" + executable);

            if (executable.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                // exe. the process
                String scenarioName = testSuite.readCell(
                        testSuite.getCell("TestScenario"), i);
                System.out.println("Scenario Name=" + scenarioName);
                handleScenario(scenarioName);
            }
        }
        WritableData writableData= new WritableData(TEST_SUITE_PATH,"Login");
        writableData.shSheet("Login", 5, 1, "Pass");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        writableData.shSheet("Login", 5, 2, "Fail");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        writableData.shSheet("Login", 5, 3, "N/A");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private void handleScenario(String scenarioName) throws Exception {
        ExcelHandler testScenarios = new ExcelHandler(TEST_SUITE_PATH);
        testScenarios.setSheetName("Login");
        testScenarios.columnData();
        int rowWorkBook1 = testScenarios.rowCount();
        for (int j = 1; j < rowWorkBook1; j++) {
            String framWork = testScenarios.readCell(
                    testScenarios.getCell("FrameworkName"), j);
            String operation = testScenarios.readCell(
                    testScenarios.getCell("Operation"), j); // SendKey
            String value = testScenarios.readCell(
                    testScenarios.getCell("Value"), j);
            System.out.println("FRMNameKK=" + framWork + ",Operation="
                    + operation + ",Value=" + value);

            handleObjects(operation, value, framWork);
        }
    }

    private void handleObjects(String operation, String value, String framWork)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("HandleObject--> " + framWork);
        ExcelHandler objectRepository = new ExcelHandler(
                OBJECT_REPOSITORY_PATH, "OR");
        objectRepository.columnData();
        int rowCount = objectRepository.rowCount();
        System.out.println("Total Rows in hadleObject=" + rowCount);

        for (int k = 1; k < rowCount; k++) {
            String frameWorkName = objectRepository.readCell(
                    objectRepository.getCell("FrameworkName"), k);
            String ObjectName = objectRepository.readCell(
                    objectRepository.getCell("ObjectName"), k);
            String Locator = objectRepository.readCell(
                    objectRepository.getCell("Locator"), k); // SendKey

            System.out.println("FrameWorkNameV=" + frameWorkName
                    + ",ObjectName=" + ObjectName + ",Locator=" + Locator);

            if (framWork.equalsIgnoreCase(frameWorkName)) {
                operateWebDriver(operation, Locator, value, ObjectName);

            }
        }
    }

    private void operateWebDriver(String operation, String Locator,
            String value, String objectName) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Operation execution in progress");
        WebElement temp = getElement(Locator, objectName);
        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("SendKey")) {
            temp.sendKeys(value);
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click")) {
            temp.click();
        }

        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Verify")) {
            System.out.println("Verify--->" +temp);
            temp.isDisplayed();

        }

    }

    public WebElement getElement(String locator, String objectName)
            throws Exception {
        WebElement temp = null;
        System.out.println("Locator-->" + locator);
        if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.id(objectName));

        } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(objectName));
            System.out.println("xpath temp ----->" + temp);
        } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.name(objectName));
        }
        return temp;

    }
}
```

**WritableData**

```
public class WritableData {

    Workbook wbook;
    WritableWorkbook wwbCopy;
    String ExecutedTestCasesSheet;
    WritableSheet shSheet;

    public WritableData(String testSuitePath, String OBJECT_REPOSITORY_PATH) throws RowsExceededException, WriteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


         try { wbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(testSuitePath)); 
         wwbCopy= Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(testSuitePath),wbook);
         System.out.println("writable workbookC-->" +wwbCopy);
         shSheet=wwbCopy.getSheet("Login");
         System.out.println("writable sheetC-->" +shSheet); 
         //shSheet = wwbCopy.createSheet("Login", 1); 
         } catch (Exception e) { 
             // TODO: handle exception 
             System.out.println("Exception message" + e.getMessage()); e.printStackTrace(); } }

          public void shSheet(String strSheetName, int iColumnNumber, int
          iRowNumber, String strData) throws WriteException, IOException { 
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        System.out.println("strDataCC---->>" +strData);
        System.out.println("strSheetName<<>><<>><<>>" +strSheetName);

          WritableSheet wshTemp = wwbCopy.getSheet(strSheetName);
          shSheet=wwbCopy.getSheet("Login"); 

          WritableFont cellFont = null;
          WritableCellFormat cellFormat = null;

          if (strData.equalsIgnoreCase("PASS")) { 
          cellFont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 12);
          cellFont.setColour(Colour.GREEN);
          cellFont.setBoldStyle(WritableFont.BOLD);

          cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
          cellFormat.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN); }

          else if (strData.equalsIgnoreCase("FAIL")) { 
          cellFont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 12); 
          cellFont.setColour(Colour.RED);
          cellFont.setBoldStyle(WritableFont.BOLD);

          cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
          cellFormat.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN); }

          else { cellFont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 12);
          cellFont.setColour(Colour.BLACK);

          cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
          cellFormat.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN);
          cellFormat.setWrap(true); }

          Label labTemp = new Label(iColumnNumber, iRowNumber, strData,
          cellFormat);
          shSheet.addCell(labTemp); 
          System.out.println("writableSheet---->"+shSheet);

          wwbCopy.write(); 
          wwbCopy.close();
          wbook.close();
}
}
```

**Console:**

```
writable sheetC-->jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl@ee1ede
strDataCC---->>Pass
strSheetName<<>><<>><<>>Login
writableSheet---->jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl@ee1ede
strDataCC---->>Fail
strSheetName<<>><<>><<>>Login
writableSheet---->jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl@ee1ede
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jxl.write.biff.File.write(File.java:149)
    at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.write(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:706)
    at com.chayan.af.WritableData.shSheet(WritableData.java:86)
    at com.chayan.af.MainClass.handleTestSuite(MainClass.java:77)
    at com.chayan.af.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:48)
```

Comment: 1. Please provide your "main" method, since it's the method which causes NPE
2. Your whole code is in constructor. What's the purpose of it?

Comment: @RafałLaskowski I have update the code with main method, please check and revert. Also, I hope after seeing the code you get the answer of your second point.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: @RafałLaskowski I have given console also for NPE, anyways please check the below line where I get the NPE: 
at com.chayan.af.WritableData.shSheet(WritableData.java:86) wwbCopy.write(); 
at com.chayan.af.MainClass.handleTestSuite(MainClass.java:77) writableData.shSheet("Login", 5, 2, "Fail"); 
at com.chayan.af.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:48) main.handleTestSuite();